# Transfering live yii2 website to localhost

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a live website built on yii2 framework and i want to test it localy using MAMP ,I created a new database named **demoDB** in phpmyadmin and import sql from live one, the updated database configuration inside the **common/config/main.php** file to the my local database authentication settings.

```
'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=demoDB',
         'username' => 'demo',
        'password' => 'demopass111',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
```

but when i run MAMP the frontend only show directory like this

[frontend path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3H7p.png)

I also tried to run command

```
php yii serve
```

on project file but i got this error

```
Document root "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/demoweb/console/web" does not exist.
```

anyone can help what I'm missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to point your server document root to the right location.

in case of yii2 it has two separate folder called `backend` and `frontend`.

so if you try to serve your site using php built-in server you can use the following command  from your project root to serve your site locally.

`php -S localhost:3000 -t frontend/web/` for the frontend part

`php -S localhost:8000 -t backend/web/` for the backend part

and your frontend and backend will be available at http://localhost:3000/ and http://localhost:8000/ respectively.

you can choose the port as your need. For example i use here `3000` and `8000`.